# Do I need to make an entirely new site if I want to use jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I would like to make a mobile version of my website and I came across jquery mobile. I was looking at examples online, I have only seen these websites make a copy of the website and put it on a subdomain or a in a /mobile/ directory on the server. I would like to keep only one form of my site so that I do not need to maintain two different sites. I have a mobile detecting script from http://www.detectmobilebrowsers.com which can detect the mobile site, but I just want to avoid making two sites. Is that possible to only have one site that can double as a mobile and desktop site? Thanks, I appreciate the help!

Comment: I think you need to be looking at responsive design if you are wanting to only use one site with multiple styles

Comment: Do you think there's anything else I can do to incorporate jquery mobile? I want it to look like a native iOS application without having to learn Objective-C and such

Comment: Thanks for not answering the question and marking it as off-topic when it isn't. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bootstrap 3 which can do exactly what you wish using its css media queries.
Alternatively you can simpy write your own CSS to be responsive using media queries.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wish you could tell me if it was possible to not use responsive design.

Comment: I would advise you to whole-heartedly use responsive design. It is a tool designed to solve the exact problem you have run into, how to make a single website display in a reactive way based on the screen resolution available to it. Embrace it like a long lost brother.

Answer (score 1):

As mccainz mentioned, you have several options. All of those examples are under an umberalla term called "responsive design".

According to **Wikipedia**, "Responsive Web design (RWD) is a Web design approach aimed at crafting sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling—across a wide range of devices (from mobile phones to desktop computer monitors)".

Now, there are many options when it comes to responsive design. Either use ready-made libraries or create it yourself.

Check the links below and see when resizing the browser how the layout changes so that you get an optimal view experience.

1. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
2. [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/)
3. [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/)
4. [HTML Kickstart](http://www.99lime.com/elements/)

All of them share the same idea: Use the great and holy CSS to decouple the layout from the real code, so that people like you who want to have the same codebase and different view experience do not have to re-write the code. Beauty of the CSS lies here.

Also, if you think above libraries do not do what you want write your own responsive CSS. For that, I highly recommend to check the following two books:

1. [HTML & CSS by John ducket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118008189)
2. [The Modern Web: Multi-Device Web Development with HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript by Peter Gasston](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CFS5V3Q)

**UPDATE**: Since you commented that you want to avoid Responsive Layouts, There are a few people who think that responsive layout does not work and then use **adaptive** approaches.Check this out [Why responsive layout does not worth it](https://managewp.com/5-reasons-why-responsive-design-is-not-worth-it). The author explains a few minimal optimziation points and believes that Responsive layouts are overkill in many circumstances. He offers techniques such as lazy loading (under section 4).

Other resource: [Alternatives to responsive design: part 1 (mobile)](http://imagerystl.com/blog/12/21/Alternatives-to-Responsive-Design-Part-One-Mobile-Websites/) discusses the issues again with responsive layout.

With adaptive approaches, it is you who decide what is a good experience on devices and you sort of do some part of optimziation with pre-coded layouts for each case, but generally there are no rule of thumbs for that. Just the books comes to my mind.

Also try liquid layouts as well.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using responsive design here. But, I appreciate the resources. Thanks!

Comment: Update my answer a bit further. Hope it will be helpful.